# Push object in array and save into mongoDB using Js

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, rest

> I want to save my details as {userId:status} into list but I'm not able to able to achieve can you help where I'm doing wrong?

```
if(campResp){
    let userId = await req.body.userId
    let status = req.body.status
    let userResp = await User.findOne({'id':req.body.userId}).exec()
    var data = {}
    data[userId] = status

    if(userResp){
        campResp.views = {}
        let visiterResp = await Campaign.find({'views':data})
        if(visiterResp.length>0){
            res.status(400).json({'status':false,'message':'Already watched'})
        }else{
            let pushResp = await campResp.views.push(data)
            if(pushResp){
                await campResp.save(async(err,response)=>{
                    if(response){
                        res.status(200).json({'status':true,'message':'campaign finished'})
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

> Schema is like, but still it's not working.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const campaignSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    imageUrl:{
        required:true,
        type:String
    },
    link:{
        required:true,
        type:String
    },
    ownerId:{
        required:true,
        type:String
    },
    setting:{
        types:{
            type:String
        },
        bill:{
            type:String
        },
        dateTime:{
            type:String
        },
        expected_time:{
            type:String
        },
        expected_views:{
            type:String
        },
        expected_subs:{
            type:String
        },
        expected_likes:{
            type:String
        }
    },
    views:[{
        userId:Boolean
    }]
},{versionKey: false},{_id:false})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Campaign',campaignSchema)
```

> and in response what it's saving how can i save into my db like userId:status. Ex "6789786722hgdvasnbad":true how to achieve the same.

```
"views": [
            {
                "_id": "609b60a82445e32e8060b0c2"
            },
            {
                "_id": "609b60a82445e32e8060b0c4"
            }
        ]
```

Comment: LIttle comment regarding database model, MongoDB uses `_id` field as a ID field for every document and generates it under the hood, you should use it instead of defined `id` field.

Comment: ohh, Thanks @Ayzrian, sure will remove my own id..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use `mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed`

```
views:[{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
}]
```

> An "anything goes" SchemaType. Mongoose will not do any casting on
> mixed paths. You can define a mixed path using Schema.Types.Mixed or
> by passing an empty object literal. The following are equivalent.

Comment: Wow, @Someone Special it's working perfect can you little explain it please.. why mine schema didn't work?

Comment: Because what you are using is a dynamic key. I don't think mongoose allow that. You can however use `mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed` which allows any data type.